# PHP Artisan migrate: Class Schema not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy estudiando `Laravel 5.4` y tengo el siguiente problema:

Al realizar una migración, en la consola de `Windows` ejecuto el comando:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Al ejecutar este comando, me muestra el siguiente error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Class
>   'Market\Providers\Schema' not found

¿Cómo puedo solucionar `Class Schema not found`? anexo el código de las migraciones:

-Para crear la tabla de productos:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name',100);
            $table->decimal('price',5,2);
            $table->integer('marks_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('marks_id')->references('id')->on('marks');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('products');
    }
}
```

-Para crear la tabla de Marcas

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateMarkTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('marks', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name',50);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('marks');
    }
}
```

-Codigo de AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace Market\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Agrega por favor el código de todas las migraciones. Haz clic en el botón editar.

Comment: Has probado ejecutar los comandos: `composer dump-autoload` y
`composer update`?

Comment: @Shaz gracias por la sugerencia amigo, ya agregue el codigo

Comment: @Jemonge intente ejecutando los comandos que me sugeriste pero el problema aun persiste

Comment: @Shaz acabo de ejecutar el comando que me dices y el resultado del error es el mismo que indico en la pregunta.

Comment: La verdad es muy raro, simplemente estás intentando cargar la clase de un namespace distinto (relativo a un provider por lo que veo), ¿puedes mostrarnos ahora el contenido de app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php?

Comment: Listo @Shaz acabo de colocar el codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que muestras en el código de tu AppServiceProvider.php, no estás incluyendo la clase del Facade desde el namespace adecuado, simplemente replica el `use` que está en las migraciones:

```
<?php

namespace Market\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: He podido solucionar el problema al agregar `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema `. Mil Gracias amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Al cargar el service provider no encuentra la clase indicada, bien porque no la has puesto correctamente o porque no la pusiste. Abre el fichero "../app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php"
y antes de la definición de la clase indica que vas a usar la clase **Schema**, **indicando el namespace completo**:

```
use \Market\Providers\Schema;
class AppServiceProvider extends  ServiceProvider
{
...
```